# MethodImplOptions.Synchronized not found in Metro

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I tend to create a synchronized method by using

`[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]`

However, I realize `MethodImplOptions.Synchronized` is not found in Metro.

Hence, what is the equivalent replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Hence, what is the equivalent replacement?

`MethodImplOptions.Synchronized` is just an equivalent for these constructs:

```
lock(this)
{
    InstanceFoo(); // instance method
}

lock(typeof(MyType))
{
    StaticFoo(); // static method
}
```

you can use regular `lock`, but I strongly recommend to not lock on `this` and `typeof()`.